# Loopback verification email http://https://example.api.com:port

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, loopbackjs

I am currently attempting to run

```
member.verify()
```

from within my loopback application, the email sends out absolutely fine except that the url is being formatted in the following way, on the email:-

```
http://https://example.api.com:port
```

The members.js has the following code in to send the email on creation of a new member:-

```
Member.afterRemote('create', function(context, member, next) {
  console.log('Sending Verification Email');

  var options = {
    type: 'email',
    to: member.email,
    from: 'noreply@example.com',
    subject: 'Thanks for registering.',
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/verify.ejs'),
    redirect: 'https://' + config.host + '/login?verified=true',
    user: member
  };

  member.verify(options, function(err) {
    console.log('Verification Email sent:', member, options, err);
    if (err){
      next(err);
    }else{
      next();
    }
  });

});
```

The verify.ejs just contains:-

```
This is the html version of your email.
<strong><%= text %></strong>
```

Has anybody else had this issue or know how to resolve it?

Also does anybody know how to remove the port number from the end of the URL?

If you require any other information please let me know.

EDIT:-

I have found the following code inside the API's node_modules/loopback/common/models/user.js

```
var displayPort = (
  (verifyOptions.protocol === 'http' && verifyOptions.port == '80') ||
  (verifyOptions.protocol === 'https' && verifyOptions.port == '443')
) ? '' : ':' + verifyOptions.port;

var urlPath = joinUrlPath(
  verifyOptions.restApiRoot,
  userModel.http.path,
  userModel.sharedClass.findMethodByName('confirm').http.path
);

verifyOptions.verifyHref = verifyOptions.verifyHref ||
  verifyOptions.protocol +
  '://' +
  verifyOptions.host +
  displayPort +
  urlPath +
  '?' + qs.stringify({
    uid: '' + verifyOptions.user[pkName],
    redirect: verifyOptions.redirect,
  });
```

Is there any way I can overwrite this information?

Comment: I'm not familiar with loopback.js, but it looks like you should specify `options.protocol: https` instead of including that in the `options.redirect`.  Also, in the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Registering-users.html#registering-users-through-a-third-party-system), it looks like `options.redirect` should only be a path (i.e. not include the protocol, host or query string).  You may want to look at the docs and the examples they link to to figure out how to need to configure the options.

Comment: Also, it looks like the `redirect` option is used to redirect the user to a page once the user has been verified, so you could just create a landing page for the verified state instead of using a query string.

Comment: Hey c1moore , thanks for the response, the options.redirect is appended to the end of the url eg ?redirect=https://example.com, this is so loopback redirect the user to a specific page after the call has been completed. This can be seen in the penultimate line of the last code block I submitted. The redirect has no bearing on the first part of the URL protocol or port number.

Comment: I realize that, but I'm guessing loopback assumes the host is the same as `options.host`.  Take a look at their official example for [verifying users](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management/blob/master/common/models/user.js#L19)

Comment: I have just tested removing the redirect and 2nd adding redirect: '/verified' in the options but the http://https:// remains at the beginning of the link in the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have managed to resolve this issue using the following:-

```
var options = {
  type: 'email',
  to: member.email,
  from: 'noreply@clientplan.com',
  subject: 'Thanks for registering.',
  template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/verify.ejs'),
  redirect: 'https://client-plan-app.herokuapp.com/admin',
  user: member,
  protocol: 'https',
  port : '443'
};
```

I have added the following lines to resolve this issue:-

```
protocol: 'https',
port : '443'
```